# Multiple Java images of same program exec same C program each to read its stdout

Tags: java, c, interprocess

Java program A execs itself twice, each of the 3 images exec the same C program with different args; the C programs send data back via `stdout` (e.g. `fprintf(stdout,...)`) to its Java peer which uses `getInputStream()` to open a reader for it.

This works well if A runs by itself, but with 3 copies of A simultaneously, only one program delivers data - the rest get freeze.

I assumed each C program has its own copy of `stdout`. Is that wrong?

I just want to make sure this architecture is correct, because it will tell me what to debug - each A is also a socket server to other Java clients.

Comment: It is not clear to me. How many JVMs at a time ? Why do you say "twice" and then mention 3 ? And finally, why don't you try whatever you want to achieve and see the result ?

Comment: Oh, are you concerned that the standard output/input would not support multiple programs sharing information on it at the same time ?

Comment: The first JVM execs two more so there's 3. I tried it and one stdout delivers whereas the others do not.

Comment: Why don't you just write to temporary files ?

Comment: Yes, each process has its own stdin and stdout (and stderr), but without code it is difficult to say what the problem might be.

Comment: Can't use files because a read does not remove data. These processes are in an embedded Linux sys that runs 24/7

Comment: A temp file can be wiped after it has been used. That's the point of a temporary file actually

Comment: There's no time to wipe out anything in a real-time system - you could lose data if you do.

Comment: Thanks David, this now tells me I can actually proceed to messy debugging details.

Comment: Make sure you don't have deadlock situation like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054531/correct-usage-of-processbuilder

Comment: In this case the architecture is the problem: each C program accesses the same hardware registers concurrently and that is the end-problem. Need some kind of Linux shareable semaphore I guess.